# Firebase Phone Auth Error FIRAuthErrorCodeMissingAppToken

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this error from firebase when trying to sign in with a phone number on iOS

```
error_name: 'ERROR_MISSING_APP_TOKEN',
NSLocalizedDescription: 'There seems to be a problem with your project\'s Firebase phone number authentication set-up, please make sure to follow the instructions found at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth' },
domain: 'FIRAuthErrorDomain'
```

I've followed all the linked directions (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) to enable phone authentication and add APNs Keys, etc.

What "token" is missing to cause this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried downloading new config files since upgrading to phone auth? Any chance you're using one downloaded before Phone Auth was released?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yeah - I was using an outdated version of firebase core in my cocoapods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the answer was pretty simple, I was using an outdated version of the Firebase iOS components. I updated my Podfile and installed the newest version and everything started working.

Answer (score 2):

We were having the same problem. Turns out we should have used **a real device with a working SIM card inside**. 
Try it out. Hope it helps.